# Inconsistent behavior with int() and float()

Tags: python, floating-point, int

In python, when converting strings to floats, `float()` converts both integers or decimals representations to a number:

`float('3.5')` gives `3.5`

`float('3')` gives `3`

`float()` also converts integers to floats:

`float(3)` gives `3.0`

Why does `int()` not convert a string decimal to an integer if it can convert a float to an integer? For example:

`int(3.5)` gives `3`,

however `int('3.5')` raises an `ValueError`exception.

This makes one use something like `int(float('3.5'))` when wanting to convert a string into an integer while not knowing whether or not the number will be a decimal.

Why is there this difference between `float()` and `int()`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score -1):

I would say, why not?

This is more like a precaution of conversion. It tries to be careful and conservative as conversion can lost data precision in an unexpected way. By saying `int(float("3.5"))`, your intention is explicit. But `int("3.5")` -- do you expect that is not an integer and you are ready to give up that 0.5 difference? Such issue does not exists in `float("3.5")`.

If you want `int("3.5")` to give you back the integer without raising error, would it be natural to also ask for `int("four")`, `int("3.5 # ignore this comment")`, `int("XLII")` to be valid? That would be too much.

Comment: Why then `float("3")` works? Isn't it converting a string that has an integer number to a float? Instead of throwing an error, it could truncate to a integer. Also I don't appreciate the sarcasm of your examples of "four" and "XLII"